# What does "changeset stripped" mean?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Under the column `Recent Activity` on a Bitbucket repo, there's the following entry:

[image]

What does this mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Changeset stripped from `<repo-name>`

is Bitbucket parlance for

> this commit used to be in the history of `<repo-name>`, but has since been deleted by a force push.

You can reproduce the situation in a toy repository. Create an empty repository on Bitbucket, clone it, then `cd` to the clone's root directory and run the following:

```sh
# create a first commit
$ touch README
$ git add README
$ git commit -m "add README"
$ git push -u origin master

# create a second commit
$ printf "hello world\n" > README
$ git commit -am "modify README"
$ git push

# "delete" the second commit
$ git reset --hard master^
$ git push --force
```

In the remote repo, under Recent history, the second commit (now deleted) will be marked as *Changeset stripped from `<repo-name>`*:

[image]